# Finding the closest non-zero cell in a 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays

I've a 2D array of booleans. I'm trying to find an algorithm to traverse this array and create a new int array which prints out the closest true from each cell.
Thus if we have a boolean, like

```
0 1 0
0 0 0
0 0 1
```

Then my int array would be,

```
1 0 1
1 1 1
2 1 0
```

I tried traversing the array and using this function,

```
private static int checkClosest(boolean[][] check, int row, int col){
    int dist =0;
    int rowDist = 0;
    int colDist = 0;
    int diagDist = 0;
    for(int i=row; i< check.length;i++){
        if(check[i][col]){
           rowDist = (i-row);
            break;
        } 

    }
    for(int i= col; i<check[row].length; i++){
        if(check[row][i]){
           colDist = (i - col);
            break;
        } 

    }
    int count=0;
    for(int i= row, j= col; i < check[i].length; i++){
        if(check[i][j]){
           diagDist = count;
            break;
        }
        count++;
        j++;

    }
    dist = Math.max(rowDist, colDist);
    return Math.max(dist, diagDist);


}
```

But this doesn't work. Can someone help me with an optimal way of doing this.

Comment: would you please elaborate a little bit more your question @Zeus ?

Comment: See the provided example. That should clearly explain the problem.

Comment: sorry i got it this time actually.. but your double dimensional  array should be fixed or may vary?? @Zeus

Comment: Does it hold the manhatan distance ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is completely wrong.

Well this function finds the minimum manhattan distance to the closes true cell for a given gell specified by row, col. All you have to do is iterate through the entire 2D array and find the closest one

```
private static int checkClosest(boolean[][] check, int row, int col){

    int minDist = 1000;    //Some really high value

    for(int i=0; i < check.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; i < check[i].length; j++){
            if(check[i][j]){
                minDist = Math.min(minDist , Math.abs(row-i)+Math.abs(col-j));
            }
        }
    }

    return minDist;
}
```

There are definitely more efficient ways to do this, but I wouldn't want to overwhelm you with that.